# Creating WCF Service and deploying it to run in Sitecore context

Tags: sitecore

We have a need to add sitecore items programmmtically. To achieve this we are basically creating new WCF Service as the standard webservice provided by sitecore is not serving our purpose. The new WCF service created in VS2010 is pushed/published to same folder as standard webservice(sitecore/shell/webservice). For some reason the service doesn't work at all throws configuration errors.

Could anyone let me know where exactly this custom service should be deployed.

Comment: Are you able to share any more information about the configuration errors?

Comment: Iam getting this error "The type 'TestGMIService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found."Let me give more details on how Iam doing it and then the error, probably that will give more insight to the errors.

Comment: Iam getting this error "The type 'TestGMIService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found". Let me give more details on the steps followed, probably that will give more insight to the errors. After creating the WCF service in VS2010, its published to following folder (C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\SDNPoc\Website\sitecore\shell\WebService). To make it work the following entries are removed from web.config Targetframework attribute and <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

Answer (score 0):

I had lots of issues deploying both WCF and old-style (.ASCX) web services in a Sitecore-controlled application.  I never was able to find a satisfactory solution, even after speaking with their tech support.  I ended up creating my own HTTP handlers to accept POST data and used those instead of WCF.  I know it's not the best solution, but it worked.